# Need help with the proof of the following theorem of the equation $x^4+y^4=z^4$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Theorem 7-2. The equation $x^4+y^4=z^4$ is not solvable in nonzero integers.

Proof: It suffices to show that there is no primitive solution of the equation $$x^4+y^4=z^2$$ (why?)

Suppose that $x,y,z$ constitute such solution; with no loss in generality we may take $x>0$, $y>0$, $z>0$, and y even. Writing the supposed relation in the form
$$(x^2)^2+(y^2)^2=z^2$$

we see from Theorem 7-1 (the theorem of Pythagorean triples ) that $x^2=a^2-b^2$, $y^2=2ab$,$z=a^2+b^2$ where $(a,b)=1$ and exactly one of a an b is odd. If a were even, we would have $$1 \equiv x^2=a^2-b^2 \equiv -1(mod \text{ } 4)$$

(how is the latter true)so b is even. We apply theorem of Pythagorean triples again , this time to the equation $$x^2+b^2=a^2$$
(why do we do the latter?) and obtain $x=p^2-q^2$,$b=2pq$, $a=p^2+q^2$, where $(p,q)=1$, $p>q>0$, and not both p an q are odd. From $y^2=2ab$ we have $$y^2=4pq(p^2+q^2)$$

Here any two of p, q and $p^2+q^2$ are relatively prime and hence each must be a square (why are they relatively prime and why must each of them be a square?): $p=r^2$, $q=s^2$, $p^2+q^2=t^2$, whence $t>1$ and $$r^4+s^4=t^2$$

Now $x=r^4-s^4$, $y=2rst$, $z=a^2+b^2=r^8+6r^4s^4+s^8$, so that $$z>(r^4+s^4)^2=t^4$$

or $t<z^{1/4}$. It follows that if one nonzero solution of $x^4+y^4=z^2$ were known, another solution $r,s,t$ could be found for which $rst \neq 0$ and $1<t<z^{1/4}$. If we started from $r,s,t$ instead of $x,y,z$, a third solution $r',s',t'$ could then be found such that $1<t'<t^{1/4}$, and so on. But this would yield an infinite decreasing sequence of positive integers, $z,t,t',....,$ which is impossible. Thus there is no nonzero solution. (Can you explain this better?)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your first question: why can we reduce the problem from searching for $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb (Z^*)^3$ which solve $x^4+y^4=z^4$ to searching for $(x,y,k)\in\Bbb (Z^*)^3$ which solve $x^4+y^4=k^2$, notice that $z^4$ ranges over all perfect fourth powers.  $k^2$ ranges over all perfect squares, of which the perfect fourth powers is a subset.  By reducing it to $k^2$, we are actually allowing *more* possibilities for solutions.  If there are no values of $k$, we have in fact proven a stronger statement and it implies the weaker original statement.

Comment: Your second question: note that if $a$ is even and  $b$ is odd, $a^2\equiv 0$ and $b^2\equiv 1 \bmod 4$, so $a^2-b^2 \equiv -1\equiv 3 \bmod 4$

Comment: Continuing @Joffan's thought, but since $x^2$ is odd, $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, contradicting the fact that $x^2=a^2-b^2\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, implying that we made an incorrect assumption somewhere, namely letting $a$ be even.  Therefore $a$ cannot be even and it must have been that $b$ is the even one in the pair.

Answer (score 1):

If $(x,y,z)$ is a solution to $x_1^4+x_2^4=x_3^4$, then $(x,y,z^2)$ is a solution to $x_1^4+x_2^4=x_3^2$.  This is the same thing as saying if $x_1^4+x_2^4=x_3^2$ has no solution, then neither does $x_1^4+x_2^4=x_3^4$.

$1\equiv x^2 \equiv a^2-b^2 \equiv 0-1 \equiv -1 \mod 4$, because $a$ is even and $b$ is odd, which cannot be the case.

We know $x^2=a^2-b^2$, so naturally $x^2+b^2=a^2$, for which we can apply the same trick again.

$p$ and $q$ are coprime by construction.  Whenever you have a primitive Pythagorean triple, the terms being added are coprime.  $p=r^2, q=s^2$ and $p^2+q^2=t^2$ because they are all coprime factors of a perfect square $y^2$.

The last paragraph is just saying that we could consistently construct $z>t>t'>t''>t'''>\ldots$, all of which need to be positive whole numbers, which is not possible.  That should be pretty intuitive.  For example, consider the sequence $64, 32, 16, 8, \ldots$.  If they are all positive whole numbers, then it should be pretty clear that this sequence needs to end.  *Positive* ensures you can't go into negatives, and *whole numbers* ensures that the sequence can't start squishing together.

Comment: Hello Jason M, can you elaborate on the claim that states  p,q and p^2+q^2 are perfect squares?

Comment: @daniel Let $k=p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}\cdots p_n^{r_n}$ for distinct primes $p_i$.  Then $k$ is a perfect square if and only if $r_i$ is even for all $i$, ie $k=p_1^{2s_1}p_2^{2s_2}\cdots p_n^{2s_n}$.  Now if $k=lm$ for coprime $l$ and $m$, then if $p_i$ divides $l$, $p_i$ cannot divide $m$.  Since $l$ and $m$ split the prime factors of $k$ and none of $p_i^{2s_i}$ can be in $m$, $p_i^{2s_i}$ must be a factor of $l$.  So then all the powers of the prime factors of $l$ are even, and so $l$ is a perfect square.  In other words, coprime factors of a perfect square are perfect squares.

Comment: I see things in the following way. Based on your notation $k=lm=p_1^{2s_1}p_2^{2s_2}****p_n^{2s_n}$, so each $p_i^{2s_i}$ must either divides $l or m$, so each power of the factors is even. I just have one more question and I think it's very basic. Is it possible that if for example $k=p_1*p_2*p_3=n*j$ and $p_i$ doesn't divide any of the factors $n,j$, can $p_j$ divide the product $n*j$.

Comment: @daniel I don't understand the question.  Do you mean $p_1\cdot p_2 \cdot p_3 \cdot n \cdot j$?  You also used $j$ twice; once in $p_j$ and once as just $j$.

Comment: For example let's assume  there exists an integer k with factors n and l and the prime number p divides k, so if p doesn't divide n  nor l, can p divide the product?

Comment: @daniel Euclid's Lemma (one of the first theorems in number theory) says if a prime $p$ evenly divides a product, say $lm$, then $p$ must divide $l$ or $m$.  This is the same as saying if $p$ does **not** evenly divide both $l$ and $m$, then $p$ does **not** evenly divide $lm$.

Comment: Right, how do we know that $p_i^{2s_i}$ divides one of the factors If it's not a prime a number

Comment: @daniel Well obviously $p_i$ has to divide either $l$ or $m$, and since $l$ and $m$ are coprime, they can't share any factors (besides 1).  In other words, $p_i$ can't divide _both_ $l$ and $m$.  So the factor $p_i^{2s_i}$ must be entirely contained in either $l$ or $m$.

Comment: it still doesn't crack to me totally but almost. How do we know that $l$ will have two factors of the same kind?. Something in the form $l=p_1*p_1*m$

Comment: @daniel When you factor out $k$ into prime factors and say $k=lm$, then some of the prime factors of $k$ go to $l$ and the rest go to $m$.  Furthermore, since $l$ and $m$ are coprime, **they cannot have any prime factors in common**.  So if for example $p_1^6$ divides $k$, then we **cannot** have $p_1$ dividing $l$ and $p_1^5$ dividing $m$, because then $p_1$ would evenly divide both $l$ and $m$, contradicting the fact that they are coprime.  I would greatly encourage you to try many examples.  Get down the basics first before tackling this.

Comment: I got it, so either the prime factors go to l or m and it doesn't matter if they are the same. Now in the last paragraph, how are $r,s,t$ also solutions?

Comment: From the equations, I see that $t$ is a parameter of the solution but how can it be a solution?

Comment: @daniel I'm serious man, this is too many questions for what should be an elementary theorem. $r,s,$ and $t$ are a solution because $r^4+s^4=t^2$ by construction, which is exactly what it means to be a "solution"; ie they satisfy the original equation. This equation came from the fact that $p, q$ and $p^2+q^2$ are perfect squares, and THAT came from the previously mentioned fact about coprime factors.

Comment: I got it at the end, so all the issue was showing that we can't infinitely generate a solution which is less than the first one because  if we decrease positive whole numbers, eventually the sequence must terminate. Thank you so much for your patience and altruistic sense

Comment: @daniel No problem, but if you still struggled with this argument, I would HIGHLY suggest some more practice with the basics of number theory. Get a good feel for relatively prime and prime factorizations. These are some of the most important properties of number theory, and Fermat (for whom this proof is credited) tends to assume the reader knows these basics.

Comment: Tomorrow I will post a question about pell's equation. Which topics do you recommend to review before start grinding?