# how would I find a Pythagorean triple that is all square numbers? (a^2)^2 + (b^2)^2 = (c^2)^2

Tags: calculus, pythagorean-triples

I started out with the thought that I could use the imaginary plain to help me as you use that to find Pythagorean triples however I have gotten nowhere can anyone help?
at the end I should have a Pythagorean triple that can look like this:
a^4 + b^4 = c^4

Comment: Fermat proved that it is impossible if $x,y,z$ are rational, $xyz\ne 0$

Comment: A sledgehammer: look up Fermat's Last Theorem. More like a nuke . . .

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863829/need-help-with-the-proof-of-the-following-theorem-of-the-equation-x4y4-z4

Comment: A good idea, but... doomed. :)